# Вложенный оператор switch

Tags: java, android

Объясните пожалуйста в чём ошибка.

Хочу использовать вложенный оператор `switch`, но где то явно что то упускаю, суть в том что при нажатии на одну из 4 картинок снизу, сверху должна появиться та на которую нажал, а оно не выходит, и ошибок не выдаёт.

Может ли это быть из за того что `button` не относиться к `View`?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button:
            switch(v.getId()) {
                case R.id.imageView1:
                    mainImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.image1);
                    break;
                case R.id.imageView2:
                    mainImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.image1);
                    break;
                case R.id.imageView3:
                    mainImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.image1);
                    break;
                case R.id.imageView4:
                    mainImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.image1);
                    break;
            }
            break;
        case R.id.button2:
            switch(v.getId()) {
                case R.id.imageView1:
                    mainImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.image2);
                    break;
                case R.id.imageView2:
                    mainImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.image2);
                    break;
                case R.id.imageView3:
                    mainImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.image2);
                    break;
                case R.id.imageView4:
                    mainImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.image2);
                    break;
            }
            break;
        case R.id.button3:
            switch(v.getId()) {
                case R.id.imageView1:
                    mainImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.image3);
                    break;
                case R.id.imageView2:
                    mainImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.image3);
                    break;
                case R.id.imageView3:
                    mainImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.image3);
                    break;
                case R.id.imageView4:
                    mainImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.image3);
                    break;
            }
            break;
            }
    }

    public void photo(){

        mainImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mainImageView);

        imageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        imageView2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        imageView3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
        imageView4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView4);

        imageView1.setOnClickListener(this);
        imageView2.setOnClickListener(this);
        imageView3.setOnClickListener(this);
        imageView4.setOnClickListener(this);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При нажатии на какой-либо виджет (в Вашем случае кнопка или картинка), вызывается коллбэк `onClick(View v)`, где `View v` соответствует нажатому виджету.

Насколько я понимаю, `onClick(View v)` у Вас срабатывает при нажатии на картинку. В таком случае `v.getId()` не сможет отдать Вам идентификатор `R.id.button` (и остальные идентификаторы, соответствующие другим кнопкам).

> суть в том что при нажатии на одну из 4 картинок снизу, сверху должна появиться та на которую нажал, а оно не выходит, и ошибок не выдаёт.

Для решения этой задачи вложенный `switch` не нужен, достаточно всего одного `switch`'а:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()) {
        case R.id.imageView1:
            mainImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.image1);
            break;
        case R.id.imageView2:
            mainImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.image2);
            break;
        case R.id.imageView3:
            mainImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.image3);
            break;
        case R.id.imageView4:
            mainImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.image4);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

> Может ли это быть из за того что `button` не относиться к `View`?

`Button` как раз относится к `View`:

```
class Button extends TextView {...}

class TextView extends View  {...}
```

поэтому `Button` можно скастовать к `View`.

Comment: Так я делал, просто мне надо знать какую кнопку я нажал, от этого у меня зависит  какие 4 картинки там будут

Comment: @Паша Васильев, Про это Вы ничего не говорили. Нажимаете кнопку -- присваиваете какой-либо переменной определенное значение, потом, принажатии на картинку второй `switch` по значению этой переменной.

Comment: извиняюсь не правильно выразился, в итоге сделал вот так.
`
public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()) {
            case R.id.imageView1:
                drawable = imageView1.getDrawable();
                mainImage.setImageDrawable(drawable);
                break;
            case R.id.imageView2:
                drawable = imageView2.getDrawable();
                mainImage.setImageDrawable(drawable);
                break;`